# Error when using itext to merge Pdfs via byte array in RJB

Tags: java, itext, rjb

Using rjb with ruby 1.9.3 and itext 4.2.0:

What I'm trying to do is to merge tiff files into pdfs.  However, I would like to the merge to happen in memory rather than saving the conversion of the tiff to pdf to a file and then running a combine on the files.  Rather than supply PdfReader with a filename, I have seen some examples saying it can also take a Byte Array as an input.  I can get the file version working, but I get an error when I use a ByteArrayOutStream, and I'm not sure why.

The following seems to work fine when using a filestream:

```
def tiff_to_pdf_by_file(image_file_name)
  @document = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.Document')

  @tifreader = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage')
  @randomaccess = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray')

  @pdfwriter = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter')
  @filestream    = Rjb::import('java.io.FileOutputStream')

  pdf = @document.new

  @pdfwriter.getInstance(pdf, @filestream.new('test_temp.pdf'))

  pdf.open()

  ra = @randomaccess.new(image_file_name)
  pages = @tifreader.getNumberOfPages(ra)

  (1..pages).each do |i|
    image = @tifreader.getTiffImage(ra,i)
    scaler = ((pdf.getPageSize().getWidth() - pdf.leftMargin() - pdf.rightMargin()) / image.getWidth() * 100)
    image.scalePercent(scaler)
    pdf.add(image)
  end

  pdf.close()

  return 'test_temp.pdf'
end

@pdfreader     = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader')
@pdfcopyfields = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopyFields')
@filestream    = Rjb::import('java.io.FileOutputStream')
filestream = @filestream.new('new_combined_pdf.pdf')
copy = @pdfcopyfields.new(filestream)
copy.addDocument(@pdfreader.new(tiff_to_pdf_by_file('test_image.tif')))
copy.addDocument(@pdfreader.new('test_template.pdf))
copy.close()
```

But when I try to use a byte array like the code below, I get the error "Not found as a file or resource" on the line the pdfreader reads the byte array.

```
def tiff_to_pdf_by_file(image_file_name)
  @document = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.Document')

  @tifreader = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage')
  @randomaccess = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray')

  @pdfwriter = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter')
  @bytestream    = Rjb::import('java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream')

  pdf = @document.new

  outstream = @bytestream.new
  @pdfwriter.getInstance(pdf, outstream)

  pdf.open()

  ra = @randomaccess.new(image_file_name)
  pages = @tifreader.getNumberOfPages(ra)

  (1..pages).each do |i|
    image = @tifreader.getTiffImage(ra,i)
    scaler = ((pdf.getPageSize().getWidth() - pdf.leftMargin() - pdf.rightMargin()) / image.getWidth() * 100)
    image.scalePercent(scaler)
    pdf.add(image)
  end

  pdf.close()
  outstream.flush()

  return outstream.toByteArray()
end

@pdfreader     = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader')
@pdfcopyfields = Rjb::import('com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopyFields')
@filestream    = Rjb::import('java.io.FileOutputStream')
filestream = @filestream.new('new_combined_pdf.pdf')
copy = @pdfcopyfields.new(filestream)
copy.addDocument(@pdfreader.new(tiff_to_pdf_by_file('test_image.tif')))
copy.addDocument(@pdfreader.new('test_template.pdf))
copy.close()
```

Comment: There is no official version of iText that is numbered 4.2.0. Seems like a third party has distributed a fork using the Trademarked name iText and my family name Lowagie, pretending it's the real iText. Now you're confusing the people responsible for the real iText by presenting this question as an iText question.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I will look to switch the version of iText one of the latest versions and test see if it works.